# Pydrake; TypeError in AdvanceTo() arguments

Tags: python, typeerror, simulator, drake

I tried to simulate a diagram and it works for most of the time.

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
...
diagram = builder.Build()
simulator = Simulator(diagram)
try:
  simulator.Initialize()
  simulator.AdvanceTo(float(1.5))
except RuntimeError:
  pass
```

Until at some point, the drake simulation will terminate at 0.2000000s and return a TypeError.

```
    simulator.AdvanceTo(float(1.5))
TypeError: AdvanceTo(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.systems.analysis.Simulator_[float], boundary_time: float) -> pydrake.systems.analysis.SimulatorStatus

Invoked with: <pydrake.systems.analysis.Simulator_[float] object at 0x7f59bbf169f0>, 1.5
```

I haven't seen this one before. I have tried many parameters but all simulations stop at 0.200000 second.

Am I missing anything, or what method should I try to debug?

## *Edit

I figured out why the `Simulator` is unhappy with my setup. The parameter is correctly passed to `Simulator` but there is something wrong with one `LeafSystem` in my diagram.

In my diagram, there are discrete ports connected to each other. When a value is passed to a discrete `LeafSystem`, the system needs to call a function to update values (`set_value()` ) and return those values by a pointer. However, the function do need to return a *status* by which indicate the diagram the value update has been done. Therefore, `EventStatus.Succeeded()` is required to be returned if the update is successful.

Nevertheless, I have no idea why lack of status return will result into a TypeError. I'm to be honest, fairly new to drake so I might have a bad explanation. Willing to receive any professional comments.

Comment: BTW Using `except RuntimeError: pass` is generally not a great thing; you should try to be very specific about the message (e.g. `if "MultibodyPlant's discrete update solver failed to converge"  in str(e): do_something_else(); else raise`). `pass` is also not a great behavior if you're trying to ignore simulation failures.

Comment: This does look like an odd error. Can you provide a minimal standalone script / notebook that reproduces this error?

Comment: Here's a repro patch (for a pydrake unit test):
https://gist.github.com/jwnimmer-tri/251334627b8a829726a9f708e13e0e48

Comment: The fix at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/17859 should make EventStatus handling smoother, next time around.